# Session variable always a page load behind in php?

Tags: php, session

I'm using the following code to create a captcha on my site, but when I try to read the value back from the session, it is always the previous captcha value.

```
<?php

session_start();

$captchaStr = md5(microtime() * mktime());
$captchaStr = substr($captchaStr,0,5);

$_SESSION["captcha"] = $captchaStr;

$captcha = imagecreatefrompng("../images/captcha.png");
$black = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 154, 32, 242);
$line = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 233, 239, 239);

// Draw lines
imageline($captcha, 0, 0, 39, 29, $line);
imageline($captcha, 40, 0, 64, 29, $line);

// Add captcha text
imagestring($captcha, 5, 20, 10, $_SESSION["captcha"], $black);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($captcha);

?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is and how to fix it?

Cheers

Comment: Why are you writing to $_SESSION['captcha'] **then** read from it? Can't you use $captchaStr instead?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: netcoder - I wasn't before I've just been trying to get it working - but it still does exactly the same thing if I was reading $captchaStr and then setting it. And it is being set because it has to be read on a different page that its being set on.

Comment: at what point exactly are you reading the value back from the session ?

Comment: @luke: In that case, where are you reading from session? Other than that bit in `imagestring`, there is no reading done from session, only writing.

Comment: When you say "previous captcha value" what value is that? I presume you are using this script to generate your captcha image, this is rendered on a page with an input box where the user types the text and this submitted text is then verified against the value stored in the session on the other page?

Comment: You'll have to use `session_start()` on the page before too. Otherwise two loaded resources might override each others cookie. As for `$_SESSION["captcha"]` differing in the above code snippet; use xdebug to verify. This is highly unlikely.

Comment: @netcoder: it is done in another page that I include that script in. I call that script in an img tag. So in the img tag I have: src="/lib/captcha.php". I only included that part of the code as I assumed the problem was with setting the value.

Comment: @antz29: Yes that is exactly right!

Comment: @mario: Yes I have session_start() on the other pages too. Well the values are definitely different as you can see in this image: http://i54.tinypic.com/flzn81.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to read back the captcha value from the page that contains the captcha value, something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<img src="/lib/captcha.php" />

<?php echo "Captcha is: ", $_SESSION['captcha'] ?>
```

This would never work. PHP locks the session file by default, so your captcha script can not run until the above container page completes execution. As well, since the captcha is being fetched as a seperate call, the user's browser has to initiate a call back to the server to fetch the image. This will take on the order of seconds to complete, while the container page will be done within microseconds.

In other words, the captcha generator script will very likely NEVER start running until after the container script has completed, which means the container script will never see the new captcha string in the session file.

Comment: It will never start running before not because of file lock issues, but because when browser will request for `captcha.php` - the line with `echo` has been already performed by server.

Comment: Umm, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: sorry then. Terrible english.